# pop at the beginning of playback

Tags: naudio, noise

When playing a memory stream containing wav encoded audio, the playback starts with a sharp pop/crackle:

```
ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(audio_filename));
[...]
dispose_audio();
sound_output = new DirectSoundOut();
IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(ms, new WaveFormat());
sound_output.Init(provider);
sound_output.Play();
```

That pop/crackle does not occur when playing the wav file directly:

```
dispose_audio();
NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcm = new WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(audio_filename));
audio_stream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm);
sound_output = new DirectSoundOut();
sound_output.Init(audio_stream);
sound_output.Play();
```

Same file is playing, but when the wav data are stored in a memory stream first, there is a somewhat loud pop at the beginning of the playback.

I am very much a newbie with NAudio and audio in general, so it's probably something silly, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are playing the WAV file header as though it were audio. Instead of `RawSourceWaveStream`, you still need to use `WaveFileReader`, just pass in your memory stream.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.